# Zimbra webmail acess with python

Tags: python, zimbra

Is there any script in python where it is shown how to access zimbra webmail. My goal is to login and see if there is new email and if it exists then download textual content to text file in local directory and save it.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

As it happens, I'm the maintainer of [the Python zimbra library](https://github.com/Zimbra-Community/python-zimbra), that aids a developer to access the Zimbra-SOAP-API.

You should be able to get the current release candidate by running pip or easy_install.

For your purpose, I would recommend calling the [GetMsgRequest-method](http://files.zimbra.com/docs/soap_api/8.5.0/api-reference/zimbraMail/GetMsg.html)

Comment: my problem is that i am not administrator, i want to connect as client or through web browser

Comment: That's no problem. You don't need to be an administrator to use python-zimbra. You can also use your normal username/password.

Comment: is python zimbra installed on server side or i install it on my computer?

Comment: Zimbra can be installed on either your client or the server. In both cases you simply need the URL to the SOAP-Service of Zimbra, which usually is https://<servername>/service/soap